# how to implement CSRF protection with angularjs and .net web api when we are using .html page as view

Tags: c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, csrf, csrf-protection

I am using AngularJS as front-end and .NET WebApi as back-end. I have seen lot of examples where `CSRF` protection is defined, but with `.cshtml` and they are using `@Html.AntiForgeryToken();` over there.  In my case I am not using `.cshtml` so cant use the above helper so please suggest how to do it with `HTML`.